# In ArcGIS Online, can an X/Y field be auto-populated when a point is added?

Tags: coordinates, arcgis-online, editing

I have a web map that is going to be edited by additional staff. When they create a point, a form pops up with several fields that are domain-enabled. Can the X/Y fields be auto-populated when a point is dropped? And also, can City/County/State fields be auto-populated according to what feature they are created in? This needs to be in AGOL. ArcGIS  desktop/pro solutions are not viable.

Comment: How are you exposing your web page to others, through experience builder?

Comment: No, just through a fields map. No additional webapp development around it. Just the map. But if that is a necessary step, please let me know.

Comment: Does this help : https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/field-maps/field-mobility/common-calculated-expressions-for-arcgis-field-maps/ ?

Comment: Yep. there lies the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Thank you J.R. The link brought me to this:

This code needs to be placed into an expression in the forms configurator of the field maps:

```
function MetersToLatLon(geometry) {
if (IsEmpty(geometry)) {
    return [null, null]
}
var originShift = 2.0 * PI * 6378137.0 / 2.0    
var lon = (geometry.x / originShift) * 180.0
var lat = (geometry.y / originShift) * 180.0 
lat = 180.0 / PI * (2.0 * Atan( Exp( lat * PI / 180.0)) - PI / 2.0)    
return [Round(lat, 6), Round(lon, 6)]
```

}

// Call the function and return the latitude or longitude value

MetersToLatLon(Geometry($feature))[0]